# Read XLS in PHP using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, xls, phpspreadsheet

I have a requirements to read XLS files (not xlsx) using PhpSpreadsheet and I having trouble. I tried this (as the documentation say but...)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("lista.xls");
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); // This loops through all cells,
                                                       //    even if a cell value is not set.
                                                       // By default, only cells that have a value
                                                       //    set will be iterated.
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' .
             $cell->getValue() .
             '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;

echo "<br>fin";
```

but didn't work (it worked with a xlsx file, but no with a xls file!)

Then I tried to open file differently:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
$sheet = $reader->load("lista.xls");
```

but also doesn't work...

I really need to solve this... please help!
PS: I've tried BasicExcel & PHPExcel but also didn't seem to work

Comment: I  the manual it say to use the first method you used and it will attempt identify the type automatically! Are you sure your xls file is not corrupted

Comment: RiggsFolly strange... because of your comment I tried myself to create a xls and it worked (the first method) but my client sent me quiet a few files and none worked... it seems he has a problema with his office... thanks a lot!

Comment: Try opening one of the clients files and using saveas save a version and see if that works

Comment: Also check if client is using something OTHER than Excel and just saving as an Excel file, that may explain the issue

Comment: Yes! He is exporting from some other system to an "xls file" that Office recognize but the library don't... Thank you very much! Do you want to post it as a "solution" so I mark it?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a useful problem statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would check with your Client to see if they are using real Excel or some other spreadsheet.

If they are using some other spreadsheet and exporting using a "Export as Excel" functionality that may explain why its not being recognised by PHPSpreadsheet as any of the possible valid excel formats.

In which case, and depending what is in the spreadsheet, it may be worth asking them to export their spreadsheet as a `csv` (comma delimited values) file, as that is such a simple format it should be a valid output. You could then read it using `fgetcsv()` function calls instead of having to use PHPSpreadsheet.

Comment: exactly! they are exporting from a system, not from excel itself! Thanx!

Comment: How does exporting from a system, not excel, cause the format to become unrecognized?  I am experiencing this issue, but in my case it is an `xlsx` file created in Excel.

Comment: @Arya xlsx is a whole different world that xls... xlsx it's pure xml and you don't need an excel library, you can open it in any code editor and understand it... xls is propietary so, you need them... In that case the lib seems to create the file in a way that excel itself recognize it, but other libs do not...

Comment: I am [unable to read excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64906846/6854117)

Answer (score 22):

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = './mysheet.xlsx';

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$worksheetData = $reader->listWorksheetInfo($inputFileName);

foreach ($worksheetData as $worksheet) {

$sheetName = $worksheet['worksheetName'];

echo "<h4>$sheetName</h4>";
/**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetName);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
print_r($worksheet->toArray());

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, It helps.

Comment: I am [unable to read excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64906846/6854117)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this statement

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("lista.xls");
```

and change it with this

```
$inputFileName = "lista.xls";
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile($inputFileName);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
```

Comment: I am [unable to read excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64906846/6854117) can you please check

Answer (score 0):

the catch here is to convert it to array after loading the file

```
$file = "file.xlsx";
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file);
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$data_array =  $spreadsheet->toArray();
```